# Profiling Spring Boot Web App by HTTP requests with YourKit

Tags: java, spring, profiling, yourkit, xrebel

I am trying to profile my Spring Boot application with YourKit,

The problem is that I can't get a pretty stack trace with the time that each method took within one HTTP request.

CPU tab does something that I want, but there everything is mixed without connecting to specific HTTP requests.

I used xRebel and there I could browse through the call to Controller up to the repository inside the one request. Is there something similar in YourKit?

Like this[image]